# Check if value appears twice in the same column in PHP using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Lets say I have a table:

```
id | name | city
------------------
1  | n1   | n1
2  | n2   | c2
3  | n3   | n3
4  | n4   | c4
```

I want to check if a value already exists in a slot inside a column.

Some values may appear multiple times in different columns but must not appear twice in the same column.

So for example n1 appears  in `name` but also in `city` but I don't want it to appear in name or city twice.

Using PDO

Comment: So what would be the output? One column with the unwanted values?

Comment: Before inserting into the table you check whether the value exists in any of those columns

Comment: You want to prevent it from happening, or check if it has happened.  Setting the column to be unique will prevent duplicates. You should be able to use try/catch to notify if the insert failed because of duplicates.

Comment: *...but I don't want it to appear in name or city twice...* Tell us what you **do want to see** (your desired output) from the query you're looking for based on the sample data you already provided.

Comment: I clearly need to work on my explanations. I want to check if a value exists insides a slot in a column before inserting the value. I have several columns in which a value can repeat itself but not in the same column. The output of the query should be TRUE if the value already exists in the column.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a count while grouping by the same field:

```
 SELECT COUNT(`name`) as count_name FROM `cities` GROUP BY `name` HAVING count_name > 1
```

This will give you a list of names that appear more than once.

If you want to prevent it from happening, set a unique constraint on the name field, and a unique constraint on the city field.  You can use this SQL to do that:

```
ALTER TABLE cities ADD UNIQUE (name)
ALTER TABLE cities ADD UNIQUE (city)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an sql query which works perfectly for the result you desire:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY name) AS t GROUP BY city ORDER BY id
```

`GROUP BY` is to get ditinct values from a column( Here we use `GROUP BY` 2 times for 2 columns `name` and `city`) and `AS t` is to define an alias for the derived table and `ORDER BY` is used to sort(this is optional)

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da43b/28) demo

Comment: It is unclear if you want to check the uniqueness of columns while inserting the values or while selecting them. This answer checks for uniqueness while selecting. @daves answer checks uniqueness while inserting. you can use the appropriate answer to suit you needs. :)